# Unable to inherit @Id from @MappedSuperclass from another JAR

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I would like to create a library that includes all the basic operations and models that I can use in other applications. Therefore, I created a JAR library in which I added a class called **BaseEntity**, which is intended to be the base class for other classes. I built the JAR and added it to another project using Maven. I created a class **Test** that extends BaseEntity, but unfortunately, the @Id annotation was not inherited from the base class.

In IntelliJ, an error is displayed: "Persistent entity 'Test' should have a primary key."

When I run the application, I receive an error: "Entity 'Test' has no identifier (every '@Entity' class must declare or inherit at least one '@Id' or '@EmbeddedId' property)"

BaseEntity:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class BaseEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    protected UUID id;
    @LastModifiedDate
    protected LocalDateTime modified;
    @CreatedDate
    protected LocalDateTime created;
    //getters, setters
}
```

Test:

```
@Entity
public class Test extends BaseEntity {
    private String a;
    //getters, setters
}
```

The problem only occurs when BaseEntity is in an another JAR, if I create BaseEntity in the same project application works fine.

How to make it work?

\Update:
I noticed that no field is added to the child class - I manually added @Id to 'Test' class - application started but created table consist only of two columns: 'id' and 'a' - both columns: 'modified' and 'created' are missing.

Comment: Consider adding `@EntityScan` to a Configuration class, in it include the package that contains your BaseEntity as well as the package that contains your application entities.   Something like this, `@EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.myapp.entities", "com.mysharedlibrary.sharedentities"})`

Comment: Still the same problem, additionally I noticed that no field is added to the child class - I manually added @Id to 'Test' class - application started but created table consist only of two columns: 'id' and 'a' - both columns: 'modified' and 'created' are missing.